# Mini Web Server for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-services

I wrote a VB.NET windows service and I'd like to know if there is some library or something that will provide me with a very simple mini web server. If my service is running, I'd just like to be able to type, in my browser:

http://localhost:1234

And have a status page popup. It will only be one single page and very simple html. Anyone know an easy way to do this before I attempt it on my own and over-engineer? lol

Comment: Is there any specific reason you can't use IIS?

Comment: Unfortunately I've been cornered into rolling my own in order to get my app to run on Compact Framework.  Fortunately it's an exercise I've been through many times before in other languages. :-)

Comment: Just a thought but have you thought about using the WCF self hosting core ... it lets you put up "web service" endpoints and host WCF services in them ... there's no reason why you couldn't have that return a lump of markup? ... it's a bit of a hack but it allows you to put some code behind the page if need be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found a pretty good library of what I was looking for at:

http://www.codeproject.com/cs/internet/minihttpd.asp

If anyone else needs a small mini web site, check out that link. I tried it and liked it.

Answer (score 12):

Look into the System.Net.HttpListener  class.  You can specify what port to listen to, and it's up and running pretty quickly.

Answer (score 5):

if you're using .NET 2.0 you can use `System.Net.HttpListener` to create your own web server that takes advantage of the `HTTP.SYS` component which is available from WindowsXP SP2 and Windows 2003 Server.

There's a article about hosting Web Services without using IIS using http.sys at http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/magazine/cc163879(en-us).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You should look into Windows Communication Foundation. The framework lets you host your own HTTP endpoint, on which you can serve whatever you want. Here is [a sample over at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx).

Comment: That will not help with a *HTTP* server.

Comment: Its a good start. Here's a sample on how to serve up a jpeg consumable in a web browser. Its a short way from there to serve up a simple <html><body>Hello world</body></html>. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681221.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [the Cassini server from Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived/cassini/) (or, [a variant of Cassini from UltiDev](http://ultidev.com/products/Cassini/)), which is implemented by the same technology as used when you debug ASP.NET or a Web Service from within Visual Studio without IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Cassini](http://www.ultidev.com/Products/Cassini)

Answer (score 1):

A couple more suggestions:

- [NancyFX](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Documentation) (look for self host)
- [Kayax](http://kayakhttp.com/)
- [WebServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost.aspx) (used in conjunction with a WCF service)

Answer (score 0):

Try WebDev.WebServer.exe. You can past parameter with it such us port and directory.