# POST&GET between C# and HTML

Tags: c#, javascript

So i've got a c# console project and i added a html file to the project solution. I now need to get data from text1 and text2 to two variables in program.cs by clicking button1 and then send an array of back to javascript variables data1, data2, etc...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #Button1 {
            width: 111px;
        }
    </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.timer.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "ajax.js"></script>


</head>
<body>


    <script type ="text/javascrip">
    var data1;
    var data2;
    var data3;
    var data4;
    var data5;
        </script>
    <p>
        <form id="form1" method="post" action="program.cs">
        <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="button" />
        <input id="Text1" type="text" />
        <input id="Text2" type="text" />
            </form>
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>


</body>
</html>
```

is this even possible?

Comment: Look into ASP.NET and MVC to make this easier on you. You would need ajax, web sockets or some wrappers around this to be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot post html form data to a Console app's program.cs as this.

One thing you could do is have SignalR hub running on your console app and have the SignalR javascript client call method directly to that Console app's hub.

Refer to SignalR's self host tutorial for how to host a SignalR on your console app:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host

Hope that help.

Comment: I can see how this would work. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either do [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) or [self-hosting](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-API-Self-Host-30abca12).

here's some related links:

- [Is it possible to create a standalone, C# web service deployed as an EXE or Windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013896/is-it-possible-to-create-a-standalone-c-sharp-web-service-deployed-as-an-exe-or)
- [Mini Web Server for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854993/mini-web-server-for-net)

But for more effective solution, you probably should look into node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to have a function in your C# code decorated as a WebService.

Then use ajax or jQuery Ajax for simplicity and call the WebService function. It should do the calculations you need an return you some value or array of values.

That's the whole concept. Hope it helps.

Also you could have some textboxes in your HTML that are hidden and after you finish the calculations on server side assign them the values you want and get them with Javascript afterwards.This is also possible but maybe not so elegant solution.

Here is an example from jQuery website of how to use Ajax with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
  }
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
      console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
    }
  });
```

Please visit http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and have a look to the documentation.

Comment: -1: This is really light on content. "use AJAX to call your C# function" is very much "a miracle happens here" step.

Comment: OK, i know how to post in JQuery but what i don't know is how to get the data in my c# program.